# Launch apps from the band

Tags: microsoft-band, cortana

Theory: Use Cortana on the band to launch your application on the phone, and that application will communicate with the band, allowing your band custom tile/buttons to work.

I have it working when you use Cortana on the phone, BUT when using Cortana on the band it does try to launch the app, but it hangs on Starting (app name) with your app icon (basically Cortana trying to start the app).  I don't even think it makes it to the app.xaml..

This is where I need help...

Use this page to get Cortana to launch your simple application...
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185609.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

You have to put code in your app.xaml.cs as well to navigate to the main page when coming in via voice commands.

```
protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.VoiceCommand)
        {
            Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
           // if (rootFrame == null)
            //{
                // Repeat the same basic initialization as OnLaunched() above, taking into account whether
                // or not the app is already active.
                rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

                // Do not repeat app initialization when the Window already has content,
                // just ensure that the window is active
                if (rootFrame == null)
                {
                    // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
                    rootFrame = new Frame();

                    rootFrame.NavigationFailed += OnNavigationFailed;

                    if (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated)
                    {
                        //TODO: Load state from previously suspended application
                    }

                    // Place the frame in the current Window
                    Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
                }

                if (rootFrame.Content == null)
                {
                    // When the navigation stack isn't restored navigate to the first page,
                    // configuring the new page by passing required information as a navigation
                    // parameter
                    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
                }
                Window.Current.Activate();
            }
       // }

    }
```